# Logitech Mouse MX Vertical Ubuntu 18 software

Tags: 18.04, additional-drivers

Does it exist some solution to customize **Logitech MX Vertical**?

Information from Logitech site https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/mxvertical/downloads#macPnlBar:

---

Logitech Options software lets you customize your device's settings as follows:

- Change function key shortcuts
- Customize mouse buttons
- Adjust point and scroll behavior
- Enable and disable touchpad gestures
- Get on-screen notifications when your device's battery runs low or when you press a lock key

---

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech MX Vertical                      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech MX Vertical                      id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

---

```
$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'Logitech MX Vertical':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (291): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (292): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (293):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (294):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (295): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (296): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (297):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (298):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (299):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (300): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (301): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (271): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (272):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (273):    0, 0
    Device Node (274):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (275):    1133, 16507
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (302):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (303):   1
```

Comment: What do you want to customize?

Comment: Logitech Options software lets you customize your device's settings as follows: Change function key shortcuts; Customize mouse buttons; Adjust point and scroll behavior; Enable and disable touchpad gestures; Get on-screen notifications when your device's battery runs low or when you press a lock key

https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/mxvertical/downloads#macPnlBar

Comment: You could add it to the question. I don't think you can get all of those on linux.

Comment: There is obviously no "Logitech software" for Linux.

Comment: Yep, but maybe exist something multipurpose for this group of hardware.

Comment: You can do customization using `libinput`, or `evdev` like a generic mouse.

Comment: Can you add output of `xinput` command?

Comment: @Pilot6 added to question contents.

Comment: OK, now add `xinput list-props 13`

Comment: @Pilot6 added `xinput list-props 13`.

Comment: So these are options you can tune. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/libinput.4.html

Comment: Can anyone confirm if the button customisations live on the mouse, or in software on the computer? Can I program the custom buttons on Windows, and them on Linux?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at Solaar? https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar
Its a package to configure and customize logitech periferals such as mouse and keyboard. The MX Vertical isn't on the list of supported devices but it is only a partial list and [it is in fact supported.](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/issues/1090)